# After angular 4 release, how to create specific angular 2.4 version app using angular cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Angular 4 has released, I want to learn angular 2 first. For that i tried to use angular CLI, but when i create new app using

```
ng new test-app
```

It creates the app the angular 4 version. Which command should i use to create specifically angular 2.4 app.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5648

Comment: It's [no longer supported](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5615#issuecomment-289033644) - you'll have to install an older version of the CLI, or create the 2.4 app yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to learn Angular 2 first? Angular 4 is basically Angular 2 with some improvements and changes. Angular uses [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) so 4.0 basically means some incompatible API changes were made. I think maybe you expect the difference between Angular 2 and Angular 4 is similar to the difference between Angular 1 and Angular 2? That is not the case. Angular 2 was a complete rewrite - Angular 4 is basically Angular 2.5.x if Angular wasn't using semantic versioning. So if you are just learning Angular now, I'd suggest going with 4.x

Also check out the [release schedule](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/docs/RELEASE_SCHEDULE.md#tentative-schedule-after-march-2017) for Angular for further understanding (2 major versions planned per year).

Comment: It is due to project requirement.