# Angular cli create Angular 2 app

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm using angular cli to create an angular folder structure with

```
  ng new src
```

In the package.json this add angular 4 in the dev dependencies

```
  "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
```

Is it possible to use angular cli ng new to add angular 2.4.6

Comment: 1. `angularjs` is the tag for AngularJS (Angular 1.x) 2. I think this has been asked already.

Comment: [After angular 4 release, how to create specific angular 2.4 version app using angular cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027827/after-angular-4-release-how-to-create-specific-angular-2-4-version-app-using-an?rq=1)

Comment: I wanted to create an Angular 2 app to use ng2-redux. Does ng2-redux work with Angular 4

Comment: this might help: [Angular 4, ng2-redux: Could not find a declaration file for module 'redux-logger'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44325946/angular-4-ng2-redux-could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-redux-logger), but to use angular-cli with Angular 2, you need to use an old version of angular-cli before they changed it to support 4.

Comment: I answered how to create angular 2 project using CLI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44552009/use-angular-2-instead-of-angular-4-with-angular-cli/44552117#44552117

Answer (score 0):

No, this is [no longer supported](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5615#issuecomment-289033644).

But the difference from Angular 2 to 4 is very small and not like the big change from AngularJS to Angular 2